# How to open two files concurrently with fopen ?

Tags: php, foreach, fopen

I wrote a php script that reads a log file using fopen and extracts all necessary info.

The issue is that i need to extract the info as an array concurrently from two files.

How do i do that with fopen ?

Comment: call fopen twice .. ?

Comment: that would mean doubling the reading part, which i want to avoid.

Comment: because the script will prioritize the second read in array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just call `fopen` and `fread` twice:

```
$filename1 = "file1.log";
$handle1 = fopen($filename1);
$content1 = fread($handle1, filesize($filename1));
fclose($handle1);

$filename2 = "file2.log";
$handle2 = fopen($filename2);
$content2 = fread($handle2, filesize($filename2));
fclose($handle2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many file pointers are required. You can even call fopen in loop like

```
<?php
$files = array("file1","file2","file3");
$fps = array();
foreach($files as $fls)
$fps[] = fopen($fls);

///rest of the code.
?>
```

fopen returns a pointer to the file.